# Clustered index scan in Delete query

Tags: query-performance, execution-plan

I am trying to improve the performance of the delete query below. `#ROW_IDS.Column_ID` and `Table1.ID` are big integer `values.Table1.ID` and `#ROW_IDS.Column_ID` are `clustered indexes`. Table1 has 131 million rows. `#ROW_IDS` has 2 million rows.

```
DELETE TOP (100000)
FROM [Table1]
JOIN #ROW_IDS ON Table1.ID = #ROW_IDS.COLUMN_ID
```

Here is the query execution plan -

Clustered Index scan on Table1 is 33%, Clustered index scan on ROW_IDS 0.3%, and Merge join is about 63%.

Why does the query plan have a clustered index scan instead of seeking? I am also doing research on a tipping point. Does a tipping point apply to
 Clustered indexes?

Thank you for your advice.

AMMH

Answer (score 0):

> Does a tipping point apply to Clustered indexes?

`TOP` has tipping point.Tipping point do not apply to `Clustered Index` .

Also your `TOP` is without order by.Do use `Order by Cluase`.

May be `Clustered Index` of `Table1.ID` and `#ROW_IDS.COLUMN_ID` are not in same order.

Without analysing data of both table, it is hard to say.

First Try, use order by in your exsiting query.

Second Try use Exists Clause to rewrite your query,

```
DELETE TOP (100000)
FROM [Table1]
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #ROW_IDS
        WHERE Table1.ID = #ROW_IDS.COLUMN_ID
        )
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.